# possible to call href="javascript..." with Vue component

Tags: google-maps, vue.js

I'm creating a set of google maps infowindows like this:

```
buildInfoWindow(location){
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: location.name + "<br />" + location.street + "<br />" + location.city + ", " + location.state + "<br /><a href=\'javascript:showForLocation(" + location.id + ")\'>show only items</a>"});
  return infoWindow;
},
```

It is built within a Vue component. Is there a way to have `showForLocation` be a Vue method? If not, do I need to just put this external to my Vue app?

Comment: Please share any live demo of this ?

Answer (score 1):

Reference from Vue official document https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/.

```
<div id="app-5">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <button v-on:click="reverseMessage">Reverse Message</button>
</div>

var app5 = new Vue({
  el: '#app-5',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  },
  methods: {
    reverseMessage: function () {
      this.message = this.message.split('').reverse().join('')
    }
  }
})
```

and use google map in vue, you can use vue package like: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-google-maps

Comment: thx - the problem is that this string is just generated from within a method (ie not part of the template). so I don't think I would access to v-on:click (or @click). Would I?

Comment: Could you use the google map for vue version? there is not recommend generate html string as UI with JS in MVVM model.